# min height on img without deformation

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

there is a way to put a minimum height of an image without distorting it?

example:

```
min-height: 500px
```

but without distorting it, I am creating an e-commerce and I have a problem with the upload of the image by the employees.

I would like to increase the aspect ratio setting only minimum height.

Comment: maybe this helps : http://thenewcode.com/586/CSS-Fluid-Image-Techniques-for-Responsive-Site-Design

Comment: What is your meaning of "distortion"? Blurriness? Incorrect width/height ratio?

Comment: distorted image due to a greater height, example: 100x100 image becomes 100 x 150, the face will be deformed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can control the height and width of an image using max-sizes and then set the width and height attributes to auto.

```
img {
    display: block;
    max-width:800px;
    max-height:500px;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}
```

This would resize the image keeping aspect ratio without becoming larger than the declared sizes.

you could also define the min-height the key is setting the width, height to auto to keep aspect ratio